# Extract rows from matrix and make a new matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix

```
X = [1 1;2 2;3 3;4 4];
Y = [2 4];
```

I want a resulting matrix `z` to have just rows 2 and 4 (the values in `Y`) of `X`. That is,

```
Z = [2 2;4 4];
```

Any solutions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Z = X(Y,:);
```

This is a pretty easily researched question in my opinion: the [first result](http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/Matrix-Indexing-in-MATLAB/matrix.html) for "MATLAB matrix indexing" answers your question and has a lot more general information about selecting parts of MATLAB matrices.